# No exact match installing Mono.Cecil nuget package

Tags: f#, nuget

In VS2013.4, when I try to add Mono.Cecil nuget package in my fsharp project :

```
PM> Install-Package Mono.Cecil
Installing 'Mono.Cecil 0.9.5.4'.
Successfully installed 'Mono.Cecil 0.9.5.4'.
Adding 'Mono.Cecil 0.9.5.4' to Ying.Unit.
No exact match found for removing reference 'Mono.Cecil.Mdb'. Trying case-insensitive search...
Failed to find match for removing reference 'Mono.Cecil.Mdb'.
No exact match found for removing reference 'Mono.Cecil.Pdb'. Trying case-insensitive search...
Failed to find match for removing reference 'Mono.Cecil.Pdb'.
No exact match found for removing reference 'Mono.Cecil.Rocks'. Trying case-insensitive search...
Failed to find match for removing reference 'Mono.Cecil.Rocks'.
Uninstalling 'Mono.Cecil 0.9.5.4'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Mono.Cecil 0.9.5.4'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'Mono.Cecil.Mdb'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Mono.Cecil
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

My project targets .NET 4.5 with F# 3.1 runtime (4.3.1.0).

Any thoughts ?

Thanks

Vianney

Comment: I cannot use paket : I'm behind a proxy and I have no access to amazon cloud storage.

Comment: I had the exact same error not that long ago - as soon as one of the projects in the solution had a library reference, other project failed with that error on package installation. I ended up doctoring .`fsproj` file manually to include package reference and then `Update-Package -reinstall`. Your mileage may vary :)

Comment: Thanks Patrick, removing library references allowed me to add Mono.Cecil nuget package.

Comment: About Paket, I got a failure downloading latest release. But paket convert-from-nuget did the job. paket install runs fine afterwards. The failure was misleading, I should be able to use paket now :-)