# NuGet issues when installing same package to multiple F# projects in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#, nuget

Here's the solution layout:

- FSharpNuGetTest (sln)

  - FirstService (F# 3.1 console project, .NET 4.5/4.5.2)
  - SecondService (F# 3.1 console project, .NET 4.5/4.5.2)

For the sake of an argument, let's say I want to install TopShelf from NuGet to both of those services. The error happens no matter the library, [someone else had very similar issue not that long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28504306/1180426), but it seems I can actually reliably reproduce it.

NuGet Package Manager version: 2.8.60318.734

After opening NuGet package manager console in VS2013.4 Community Edition:

```
PM> Install-Package Topshelf -ProjectName FirstService
Installing 'Topshelf 3.1.4'.
(... snip - license stuff ...)
Successfully installed 'Topshelf 3.1.4'.
Adding 'Topshelf 3.1.4' to FirstService.
Successfully added 'Topshelf 3.1.4' to FirstService.
```

Perfect. Now let's try the same thing with the other service:

```
PM> Install-Package Topshelf -ProjectName SecondService
'Topshelf 3.1.4' already installed.
Adding 'Topshelf 3.1.4' to SecondService.
No exact match found for removing reference 'Topshelf'. Trying case-insensitive search...
Failed to find match for removing reference 'Topshelf'.
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'Topshelf'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Topshelf
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Ooops...

I encountered it (again) when

1. Trying to install XUnit/NUnit to multiple F# test projects in a solution.
2. Most recently, when trying to install Akka.FSharp to multiple F# projects in a solution.

Any ideas how to fix it...?

It only happened to me with multiple F# projects - never had any issues with C# projects.

My bandaid solution is to copy & paste references from one `.fsproj` file to another. `Update-Package` even seems to be working after that operation.
That doesn't change the fact that it's a hack and not how solution management is supposed to work, especially when reinstall is needed - then you have to copy & paste all `<Reference>` elements from one `.fsproj` (the one that actually gets everything installed) to every other all over again, because NuGet package installation dies on subsequent projects...

#### Edit

It seems that brute force might work here - after c.a 4 tries, the package got installed to the second service application (?!).
That makes no sense...

I just hope I won't have to do that on CI server.

Comment: Have you considered paket? I can't say about this particular issue, but paket fixes many other issues with nuget.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Not yet. I just glanced over it, but it looks promising - but I'd have to incorporate it into CI build process - specifically TeamCity. Close integration with NuGet seems to be a big plus in this case. I'll have to research it a little bit more. You're saying that it 'fixes many other issues with nuget', what would be the major 'fixes' be?

Comment: Two examples that immediately jump to mind: conflicting package versions between projects and multiplatform targeting.

Comment: FWIW, I just tried with Visual Studio Premium 2013 and NuGet 2.8.50926.663, but I **can't reproduce** the issue. As expected, TopShelf gets correctly installed into both projects. It may be an issue with your environment.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Weird, that happens to me on two different machines (at work with VS2013 Pro and on my private machine with the setup above), and I have absolutely no idea why... It *might* be the environment, but I have no idea where to start :)

Comment: @MarkSeemann OK, it seems that if I run `Install-Package` over and over again, at one point it succeeds (?!) That's seriously confusing, but oh well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of a half-answer, but here it goes.

As I noted in the edit, brute-forcing seems to work. If it doesn't work the first time, just spamming `Install-Package` makes it work on the second (or third, or fourth...) try.

Weird...